# Solving an overdetermined sparse linear system produces high error solution

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

### My Code

So I have written an algorithm which iteratively solves a sparse overdetermined linear system. That means my code looks like this:

```
   construct_A_matrix();
   construct_B_matrix();
   while(someCondition){
    x=solveSystem(A,B) //solve Ax=B. This system is overdetermined 
                       //since A has more rows than cols.
    update_A_matrix(x) //update A based on x
    update_B_matrix(x) //update B based on x
    iterationsCounter++
    }
    useX();
```

In solveSystem I use eigen's [SimplicialLDLT](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SimplicialLDLT.html) and [Conjugate Gradient](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ConjugateGradient.html) solvers (I use both of them for debugging purposes, if the code worked I would use only one of them). The code I use to solve the system is:

for Conjugate Gradient

```
     using SpMatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
     Eigen::ConjugateGradient<SpMatrix, Eigen::Lower | Eigen::Upper>
     solver;
     SpMatrix At = A.transpose();
     SpMatrix AtA = At * A;
     solver.compute(AtA);
     EigenMatrix newVertexPositions = solver.solve(At * B);
     std::cout << "estimated error: " << solver.error() << std::endl;
     double residual=(A.transpose() * (A * x) - A.transpose() * B).norm()/(A.transpose() * B).norm();
```

and for SimplicialLDLT

```
    using SpMatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
    Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<SpMatrix> solver;
    SpMatrix At = A.transpose();
    SpMatrix AtA = At * A;
    solver.compute(AtA);
    if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
            std::cout << "Decomposition failed!" << std::endl;
    EigenMatrix AtB = At * B;
    EigenMatrix x = solver.solve(AtB);
    if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
            std::cout << "Solving failed!" << std::endl;
    //simplicialLDLT has no error() function
    double residual=(A.transpose() * (A * x) - A.transpose() * B).norm() /(A.transpose() * B).norm();
```

### The problem

**After some number of iterations of the above loop the residual/error of the solver rises and the solution I get is wrong.**

SimplicialLDLT is producing better results than Conjugate Gradient but still wrong after a while. This can be seen graphically below. As you can see SimplicialLDLT's residual grows later than Conjugate Gradient's.

[image]
[image]

So this is my problem and I am trying to figure out why this happens.**What I have noticed is that the residual grows when the values of A and B rise.update_A_matrix and update_B_matrix gradually increase the values of matrices A and B while iterationsCounter inceases.**

### Try it yourself

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/osifws03yp3oyxj/AABY0bkGfvt7JR5P-J2AmkCba?dl=0) you can find two folders one for each solver in which you will find the matrices A,B and x in market format for the last iteration of the above while block. There is also an info file in which you will find for each iteration of the above loop the maximum and minimum values of A and B as well as the values of the residual. You can load A,B and X using the code below:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse> //system solving and Eigen::SparseMatrix
#include <ctime> //measure time to execute
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra> //loadMarket

using SpMatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
using Matrix = Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main() {
  SpMatrix A, B;
  Matrix X;
  Eigen::loadMarket(A, "/AMatrixDirectory/A.mtx");
  Eigen::loadMarket(B, "/BMatrixDirectory/B.mtx");
  Eigen::loadMarket(B, "/BMatrixDirectory/X.mtx");
}
```

or in python:

```
import scipy.io as sio
A=sio.mmread('/AMatrixDirectory/A.mtx')
B=sio.mmread('/AMatrixDirectory/B.mtx')
X=sio.mmread('/AMatrixDirectory/B.mtx')
```

**I am intrested in knowing**:

1. Why the residual goes up in the first place.
2. How can I prevent it from going up.

Comment: My guess is that the matrix `A` becomes singular, especially after squaring it. You might try to fallback to `SparseQR` directly with `A`. For CG, better use `LeastSquaresConjugateGradient`, again without squaring `A`.

Comment: @ggael SparseQR produces the same results as the simplicialLDLT producing wrong results the same way and at the same iteration.  LeastSquaresConjugateGradient  fails to solve the system at the 10th iteration (which is interesting) but the [info()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1IterativeSolverBase.html#a0d6b459433a316b4f12d48e5c80d61fe) function only tells that it failed and not why.

Comment: Looking at your data, the condition number of `A` is about 1e10, so it is not surprising that any solver based on the normal equation fails. Moreover, since `A^T A` is not full rank, if `A^T B` is not in the image of ``A^T A` then your least-squares problem does not admit a solution with vanishing derivatives. So you should work on your equation to make the problem well posed.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have a sparse overdetermined system yet use a method that isn't even meant for it. When it is sparse typically one uses the lasso method, which is L1 regularization. There has been plenty of work done in that area. When you take the normal equations you square your condition number. This is a tutorial on both types of [regularization.](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-ridge-lasso-regression-python/) There is also something called compressed sensing.